# Dealing with "blank" inputs in prediction of a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks

Say I'm training a neural net to compute the following function:

```
(color_of_clothing, body_height) -> gender
```

When using this network for prediction, I can obviously plug in a pair `(c, b)` to receive a predicted `g`, but say I want to get a prediction only based on `c` or only based on `b`, can I use the same neural net somehow? Or would I need to train two separate neural nets `c -> g` and `b -> g` previously?

Or more generally, can I use a neural net that was trained to predict `A -> B` to make predictions on values from a subset of `A`, or should I train separate neural nets on all subsets of `A` that I'm interested in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer to your question would be "yes". Though inference would always be best if you provide representative training data. For example you can train your net with `(c, b)` pairs, `(blank, b)` pairs, and `(c, blank)` pairs. That would make the net more robust and likely to support your use case. Training separate nets for each case would be more efficient and accurate - but I'm not sure what your goals and constraints are.

The point is a "blank" input can be trained for as well in the same net. In your case it's a new kind of `body_height` or `color_of_clothing`. I also suspect you might have issues with how you encode `blank` because e.g. `rgb(0, 0, 0)` would be black, and perhaps you intended to model `blank` as zero which would mean a blank is black.